# (php) date and time

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

How to get date and time into one string ($moment) and if it works, can mysql do this:

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY $moment ASC`
?

Comment: Please give an example of what you $moment string looks like.

Comment: well i want it to be something like: 
14/4/2010 at 15:36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a `TIMESTAMP` or a `DATETIME` column, then the [date()](http://php.net/date) function will give you a suitable value to use in a query:

```
$moment = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");  //current time
```

The query you put in your question doesn't seem to use it at all however.  Using `ORDER BY` on a datetime/timestamp column does work though, so you'll get the result set in chronological order.

Comment: okay so if i want to order comments by example, they will be ordered chronologically automatically?

Comment: If you put an `ORDER BY someDateOrTimeColumn` into your query, then yes, MySQL handles the ordering for you.